# Grep for the 5 lines after a specific text string found in files

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have many java files, and I want to find how many times we are logging via

```
logger.isDebugEnabled(){
    logger.Debug("some debug message");
}
```

To get an idea of how often we may be overusing the isDebugEnabled function. I have found the number of times we have called/where it is called via

```
grep -r "isDebugEnabled" --include=*.java . | wc -l
```

But I want to know how many of those are 1 line statements. Does anyone have a good script to search for this or any ideas on the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Did you read the manual page for `grep`? If you want to include 5 lines after the match add `-A 5`.  E.g.:  `grep -A 5 -r "isDebugEnabled" ...`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how many of those are 1 line statements"?

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use grep for this, use the following AWK program:

```
prev ~ /isDebugEnabled/ && $0 ~ /logger\.Debug\("[^"]"\)/ {
    print FILENAME ":" NR ": " $0
}
{
    prev = $0
}
```

This program remembers the previous line in the `prev` variable and thereby allows you to compare two lines at a time.

To actually use it, write:

```
find . -name '*.java' -print \
| xargs awk 'prev ~ /isDebugEnabled/ && /logger\.Debug\("[^"]"\)/ { print FILENAME ":" NR ": " $0 } { prev = $0 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments grep provides options to print certain number of lines after and before match.

To print lines after match:

```
grep -A 2 "string to match" file.txt
```

To print lines before match:

```
grep -B 2 "string to match" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to write a script giving one final answer, try different approaches for insight what is best for what you want. Test with one file.
Do you think, that `logger.Debug("The database has ", getDbNum(), "and the server has ", getRemoteNumSpecial(), "records.");` is a simple oneliner?
You can collect some numbers for a first orientation. The examples beneath is using x.java as example sourcefile.

```
# Nr of isDebugEnabled calls
grep -c "logger.isDebugEnabled" x.java
# Some may be comment with //
grep -c "//.*logger.isDebugEnabled" x.java
# How much debug-lines
grep -c "logger.Debug" x.java
# How much debug-lines with more than 1 parameter (having a ,)
grep -c "logger.Debug.*," x.java
# How much debug-lines without the closing ) on the same line
grep "logger.Debug" x.java | grep -v "Debug.*)"
# How much logger.isDebugEnabled() without a logger.Debug on the next line
grep -A1 "logger.isDebugEnabled" x.java | grep -c "logger.Debug"
# How much logger.Debug a "}" on the next line
# The debugline might have a }, so skip lines with logger.Debug 
grep -A1 "logger.Debug" x.java | grep -v "logger.Debug" | grep -c "}"
```